# VBA Pivot Tables below each other

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched the board for solutions but I'm unable to find anything similar.

I'm trying to place about 5 pivot tables with varying rows of data below each other. I'm able to get it done with the first two, but the code is not working from the third on.

Sadly, I was asked to place them vertically across the sheet. Below is my piece of code. Sorry for the mess, but I'm kind of new to VBA. I'm using Excel 2007.

```
    Sheets.ADD.Name = "Pivot"

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "CTB!" & Sheets("CTB").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Pivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14

Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Collector")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Transaction #"), "Count of Transaction #", xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Invoice Amount"), "Sum of Invoice Amount", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Total Balance"), "Sum of Total Balance", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Days Late"), "Sum of Days Late", xlSum
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Days Late")
    .Caption = "Average of Days Late"
    .Function = xlAverage
End With

Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Application.PivotTableSelection = True
pt.PivotSelect ("Sum of Total Balance"), xlDataOnly
Selection.Style = "Currency"
pt.PivotSelect ("Sum of Invoice Amount"), xlDataOnly
Selection.Style = "Currency"
pt.PivotSelect ("Average of Days Late"), xlDataOnly
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("Pivot").Cells(Sheets("Pivot").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "C121+!" & Sheets("C121+").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=Range("A" & LastRow + 2), TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14

Dim pt2 As PivotTable
Set pt2 = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

pt2.TableRange1.Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Collector")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Transaction #"), "Count of Transaction #", xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Invoice Amount"), "Sum of Invoice Amount", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Total Balance"), "Sum of Total Balance", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Days Late"), "Sum of Days Late", xlSum
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Sum of Days Late")
    .Caption = "Average of Days Late"
    .Function = xlAverage
End With

Application.PivotTableSelection = True
pt2.PivotSelect ("Sum of Total Balance"), xlDataOnly
Selection.Style = "Currency"
pt2.PivotSelect ("Sum of Invoice Amount"), xlDataOnly
Selection.Style = "Currency"
pt2.PivotSelect ("Average of Days Late"), xlDataOnly
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "11+!" & Sheets("11+").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=Range("A" & LastRow + 2), TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14

Dim pt3 As PivotTable
Set pt3 = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable3")

pt3.TableRange1.Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Collector")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Transaction #"), "Count of Transaction #", xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Invoice Amount"), "Sum of Invoice Amount", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Total Balance"), "Sum of Total Balance", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Days Late"), "Sum of Days Late", xlSum
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sum of Days Late")
    .Caption = "Average of Days Late"
    .Function = xlAverage
End With

Application.PivotTableSelection = True
pt3.PivotSelect ("Sum of Total Balance"), xlDataOnly
Selection.Style = "Currency"
pt3.PivotSelect ("Sum of Invoice Amount"), xlDataOnly
Selection.Style = "Currency"
pt3.PivotSelect ("Average of Days Late"), xlDataOnly
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "code is not working from the third on"  You get an error? An unexpected result? What do you expect instead? Did you have a question, or just filling us in on your afternoon?

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. I get "A PivotTable report cannot overlap another PivotTable report". I was hoping it would simply insert the third PivotTable two rows under the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to update your LastRow variable each time you want to insert a new pivotTable. Then the next pivotTable will be inserted to a range beginning two lines under the last one...

You set the LastRow variable once before inserting the second pivotTable, but you have to reset it to read the current last row before you insert pivotTable3, etc, etc

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, but it won't work either. The code keeps running and supposedly places PivotTable3 somewhere, but I can't see it and then the code fails when trying to create PivotTable4. Any ideas?

Comment: Just figured it out. I had pasted it in the wrong place. Thanks a lot!